# Custom keyboard - android:codes for / (forward slash)

Tags: android, keyboard

I have a custom keyboard.  I would like the keyboard to contain a / key.

I am trying to find the android:codes for the / character (forward slash).  A line of my code follows.

```
<Key android:codes="116"   android:keyLabel="/" />
```

In the above line of code I would like to replace 116 with a number that works.

I am surprised that a Google search did not return a master list of android:codes

Thanks for your help,
Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used Code 47 and it returned a /